# Create login page and store token string

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, token

I have a WCF service, where I need to login using a username and password. The service then sends me back a token string, that I need to use when querying other methods in the WCF service. I've set the service up using wsdl2objc, and it works perfectly.
My questions are:

- Where do I store this token string? As it is right now theres no
  SQLite db on the phone, as everything is done on the backend.
- Given that it is possible to store the token, is it possible to
  create a login page, that only appears if there is no token available
  on the phone?
- Is it possible to also store my username, that I used to login, as I
  need that for some other calls to the service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

Set it as below

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:token forKey:@"myToken"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:userName forKey:@"myUserName"];
```

Get values back as below

```
NSString *token = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"myToken"];
NSString *userName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"myUserName"];
```

Comment: when you are setting value after that line use "[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

Answer (score 2):

You can use NSUserDefaults for storing token string. This link provide you a better way to understand [nsuserdefaults_iphone](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/nsuserdefaults_iphone-sdk/)

I hope it helps you...!

Answer (score 2):

storing:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"myHashKey" forKey:@"hastToken"];
```

getting:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"hastToken"];
```

Answer (score 2):

To store it use this:

```
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[standardUserDefaults setObject:token forKey:@"token"];
[standardUserDefaults synchronize];
```

And to get it back use this:

```
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *token = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"token"];
```

Answer (score 1):

`NSUserDefaults` is one of the best ways to go. Another solution is to use a singleton class that will store all the required details. Here's an example:

ServerCheck.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ServerCheck : NSObject
{
    NSString *userToken;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* userToken;

+ (id)sharedSingletonController;
@end
```

ServerCheck.m

```
#import "ServerCheck.h"

@implementation ServerCheck
@synthesize updateOnServer
+(ServerCheck*)sharedSingletonController{

    static ServerCheck *sharedSingletonController;

    @synchronized(self) {
        if(!sharedSingletonController){
            sharedSingletonController = [[ServerCheck alloc]init];
        }
    }

    return sharedSingletonController;
}

-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        userToken = [[NSString alloc]init];
        }
    return self;
}

@end
```

You can access the value as follows:

```
ServerCheck *serverData = [ServerCheck sharedSingletonController];
serverData.userToken = <YOUR TOKEN>;
```

Comment: That's not good solution. Data will be lost when app will killed or crash.